# Simple meteor insert not working

Tags: meteor

I am just getting started messing around with Meteor and can't get the following code for a simple Collection.insert to update the database when the event is triggered. I can even see the page update with the value of the text field for a split-second before disappearing (presumably once Meteor realized the value wasn't written to the server). Inserting via the console works just fine... Is there some basic concept that I am overlooking?

file.js

```
var Tasks = new Meteor.Collection("Tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.main.task = function() {
        return Tasks.find({});
    };

    Template.main.events = {
        'click #submit' : function(event) {
            var task = document.getElementById("text").value;
                Tasks.insert({title: task});
        }
    };
}
```

file.html

```
<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" id="text" class="input-small" />
        <input type="Submit" class="btn" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    {{#each task}}
        <span id="output">{{title}}</span>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your submit button issues a page reload before your javascript is executed canceling your request to the server.

Try using 'mousedown' instead of 'click' or (much better) prevent the button from doing a page reload.

Try using this snippet, it disables the submit for the button so only your javascript is executed.

```
<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" id="text" class="input-small" />
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {{#each task}}
        <span id="output">{{title}}</span>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I changed your second `<input>`-tag to button and set it's type attribute to 'button' to make the button do nothing.