# How to preserve bootstrap dropdown state on Meteor

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a bootstrap dropdown button for each table row.
When the dropdown is clicked it shows a small form with some input fields.
When the user submits this form data or the row gets redrawn the dropdown closes.

I tried preserving the dropdown state using the `Template.preserve()` method, similar to inputs but with no success.

Some suggested using `{{#constant}}` directive surrounding the dropdown I also have some reactive content inside the form that needs re-rendering, so this options is not for me.

Comment: You are not issuing a page reload on the click of the button, are you?
If so, look here on how to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191644/simple-meteor-insert-not-working/14197040#14197040

Comment: All submit events are "stopped" by `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`, just to be sure. But submit makes changes to the row collection thus re-rendering it after. I notice that the open class in the dropdown is removed every time it is re-rendered. And here is where the problem lives. I cant find a way to "isolate" only this tag and not its children from being redrawn. I tried {{#isolate}} with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed this issue with reactive templates and there is no good solution that I know of. This is somewhat of a hack but it works.

**Option 1**
Manually add and remove a css class to your dropdown. Use session variables to save the state of the dropdown.

This should be the default state of your dropdown... `class="dropdown"`
When a user clicks on the dropdown use a session variable to save its state and add 'open' to the HTML class attribute. `class="dropdown open"`
When a user closes the dropdown remove 'open'

**Option 2:**
 1. User clicks dropdown button.
 2. Save dropdown button ID as active using a session variable.
 3. Use the following callback to reopen your dropdown... `Template.myTemplate.rendered = function ( ) { 
    if (dropdown = active) {
        $().dropdown('toggle'); //instead of toggle try 'open' 
    }
}`

I haven't tried this with dropdowns yet but I was having the same issue with modals disappearing every time the template kept rendering. I tried the second option and it didn't work that great. I ended up using something like the first option to solve the issue and it worked great.